# Can you modify a private field of a super class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, private, encapsulation

I'm working with a **closed-source base class**. Can I somehow change a private field in the base class from my inheriting class?

Assuming the following class structure:

```
public class Parent
{
    private bool age;
}

public class Baby : Parent  
{
    public bool newAge{
        get {
           return age;
        }
    }
}
```

This currently gives you a compile-time error:

```
 'Parent.age' is inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

How do you access the field "age" from the Baby class? Can you use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384906/41021) or something similar?

Comment: Is the Parent class a normal class or a partial class?

Comment: The Parent class is an abstract class.

Comment: If the authors of the base class wanted you to be able to do that then they would have made the field protected. Obviously they do *not* want you doing that, so don't do it. If you want that feature added, **put in a feature request**. Don't go making dangerously brittle code that puts a dependency on an implementation detail that the authors of the class *deliberately prevented you from taking a dependency on*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could, using reflection. It looks like this:

```
public class Baby : Parent
{
    private readonly FieldInfo _ageField = typeof(Parent).GetField("age", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    public int newAge
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)_ageField.GetValue(this);
        }
        set
        {
            _ageField.SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

If it's provided by a 3rd party, there is nothing stopping them from changing it, renaming it, it removing it all together. That's one of the points of `private`. Keep in mind that it might be private for a reason. Tinkering where you aren't suppose to can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use reflection to get access to private fields and modify them. Like:

```
typeof(Parent)
.GetField("age", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
.SetValue(parent, 14);
```

where `parent` is an instance of `Parent`.

Comment: +1, though it's worth considering that in any real-world code one has to be careful with this since it can put the object into a state it doesn't expect to be in and lead to bugs that are very hard to track down.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you cannot change the source code of the parent class, there's possibly 2 choices:

1. If the parent class is a partial class, you can define your own contribution (another Parent class) defining a public Property (it can access private fields).
2. You can indeed use reflection.

Comment: He can't: `closed-source base class`

Comment: Downvoters, my apologies, I haven't seen the first statement in the question. I gave another options, so please reconsider the votes.

Comment: A partial class would only be useful if he had the source of the Parent class, I would probably just recommend changing the field to protected in the first place. Remember a partial class is a compiler feature, the runtime is completely unaware of it.

Comment: Oh you're right. Definitions of partial classes can only be made inside the same assembly. Thanks for the information. And don't downvote me under 0, folks.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* modify those values via reflection.  That being said, you probably shouldn't.

Private fields, properties, and methods are all things that are not explicitly guaranteed by the contract of the class.  If this 3rd-party API is reliable the public contracts they provide will not change (but they can easily *grow*).

The private and internal parts are not guaranteed to be the same from release to release.  By coupling your code to those parts of the code, you've introduced a lot of risk to your future releases.  If you're ok with that risk (and it's well-documented as to why you're doing it), the by all means, reflect away.

If you do go that route, I would recommend an Adapter class that all *your* consuming code uses instead of this 3rd-party API.  With the Adapter pattern, only the one class will need to change in response to the 3rd-part API changes.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do it. Unless you use reflection for example:

```
Reflection.FieldInfo fields[] = 
    myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```